# OLE Registration success, but not able to instantiate GUID?

Tags: c#, dll, gac, regasm, gacutil

I have compiled a dll let say "foo.dll" with VS2010 Premium, at the Developer level the dll works perfectly with Navision 2009 R2 (it connects with a third party dll which connects to the com port to read data).

at the production level, the registration is made by following commands:

```
   SET GACUTIL="gacutil.exe"
   SET REGASM="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe"
   %REGASM% CodeBarReader.dll /tlb:CodeBarReader.tlb
   %GACUTIL% /i CodeBarReader.dll
```

P.S: the gacutil.exe is copied to the local directory with gacutlrc.dll (this workaround is the solution for registering .net dlls)

After registering the dll successfully, and launching the Navision to read data the following error is detected:

```
Impossible to create an instance for OLE control OR Automation server identified with :
GUID={BEB37D92-3040-48A0-8CEA-4F97FAADE6EF}1.0{B5F7CE98-466E-3EB0-A88D-B7FEA3F76D7B}:'CodebarReader'unknown Class
Verifiy that OLE Control OR Automation Server are correctly installed and registered.
```

It seems that the method for registering the component is incorrect

Help is appreciated...

Comment: The error message hides the error code that would give anybody a shot at diagnosing the real reason.  It doesn't say anything more than "couldn't do it".  Anything is possible, maybe you'll find out something more by using SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You'll at least have a shot at seeing it trying to use a registry key that isn't present or trying to find a DLL that is missing.

Comment: that's what i was doing since two days with ProcMon.exe both of the pcs (Developer & Production) have the same keys & Values defined in the registry. ??